# How can we attribute observations to observers in a hierarchical Bayesian model?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, bayesian-network, pymc

I am trying to make a hierarchical Bayesian model of latent variables based on many observations by noisy oracles. I want to leverage the information of which observations are from which oracles, as I expect each oracle to be somewhat internally consistent. However, as I try to express these observations to a model using PyMC3, I can’t figure out how to do so without creating a very sparse set of observations with mostly null values.

More specifically, I have several dozen cookie recipes that I would like to infer the latent quality of. Each recipe has been implemented one or more times to create batches, and each batch has been tasted by 100 people. Each time a cookie is tasted by a person, it results in a noisy binary observation of whether the person approves of that cookie from that batch.

My problem is that while there are 30 recipes and 100+ observations per recipe, each person only provides an observation on 5 of the recipes, including 2 observations of the gold standard recipe.
This means that my observations are quite sparse - for any observation, only 5 out of 30 recipes have values. This is presumably well beyond the level at which it would be reasonable to impute missing values.

The obvious solution to this would be to consider every observation as independent and ignore attributions of observations to oracles. However, I believe that this will sacrifice a substantial amount of information, since I expect each oracle to have some internal “approval threshold” that determines which latent qualities are high enough to be observed as a 1 or 0.

My question then, is whether there is a way to express these observations to a hierarchical Bayesian model like PyMC3 without sacrificing the observation attribution information.

Comment: Your problem sounds like an IRT model (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item_response_theory). I don't know much about these; the Stan User's Guide has a chapter on this kind of model (https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_27/stan-users-guide/item-response-models-section.html). I don't know how to translate that to PyMC3 - hopefully these are enough to get you started. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @MauritsM! Those links were actually incredibly helpful! IRT is exactly the right abstraction for this. I have gotten a way-simplified version running in PyMC3 based on the indexing scheme they show in the stan guide you linked and it's working pretty well. I will post an answer to my question with it once I iron it out a bit more.

Comment: That's great! Glad to hear those links were useful. Good luck working it out - I'll keep an eye out for the answer; maybe I'll learn something too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, posting my solution below in case helpful for others.

As demonstrated in the handy guide to [IRT in Stan](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_27/stan-users-guide/item-response-models-section.html) that Maurits M posted, the key to avoiding the sparseness is to unpivot the observations and index everything against the observation index, where observation i is an observation made by person j about recipe k. To implement this, I just loop across observations, then index into person and recipe trackers to determine which distributions this observation is relevant to. The looping is actually vectorized with numpy indexing, yielding the code below.

```py
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as tt

def generate_observations():
    TASTERS_PER_VARIANT = 100

    # These parameters suppose that 2 separate tastings have been run, each with
    # 3 recipes, where each taster observes 2 out of the 3 recipes in the test
    # and the third variant (index 2) is included in both tests.
    QUALITIES = [0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.5, 0.6]
    TASTER_THRESHOLD_BOUNDS = [0, 0.9]
    VARIANTS_IN_TEST = [[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4]]
    # each sublist of PERMUTATIONS indexes into a sublist of VARIANTS_IN_TEST
    PERMUTATIONS = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 2]]
    TASTERS_PER_PERMUTATION = int(TASTERS_PER_VARIANT / 2)
    observations, taster_of_obs, formula_of_obs = [], [], []
    taster_idx = -1
    for test_set in VARIANTS_IN_TEST:
        for permutation in PERMUTATIONS:
            for _ in range(TASTERS_PER_PERMUTATION):
                taster_idx += 1
                taster_threshold = np.random.uniform(*TASTER_THRESHOLD_BOUNDS)
                for perm_idx in permutation:
                    formula_of_obs.append(test_set[perm_idx])
                    taster_of_obs.append(taster_idx)
                    observations.append(int(QUALITIES[test_set[perm_idx]] >= taster_threshold))
    return np.array(observations), np.array(taster_of_obs), np.array(formula_of_obs)

def logit(threshold, candidate, steepness=1):
    return 1 / (1 + tt.exp(steepness * (threshold - candidate)))

def run_model(observations, taster_of_obs, formula_of_obs):
    LOGIT_STEEPNESS = 10
    n_tasters = np.max(taster_of_obs) + 1
    n_formulas = np.max(formula_of_obs) + 1
    n_obs = len(observations)
    obs_idcs = np.arange(n_obs)
    with pm.Model() as tasting_model:
        formula_quality = pm.Normal("formula_quality", mu=0.5, sigma=0.3, shape=(n_formulas))
        taster_discerningness = pm.Normal("taster_discerningness", mu=0.5, sigma=0.3, shape=(n_tasters))

        discerningness_idxd = taster_discerningness[taster_of_obs[obs_idcs]]
        quality_idxd = formula_quality[formula_of_obs[obs_idcs]]
        ps = logit(discerningness_idxd, quality_idxd, LOGIT_STEEPNESS)
        top_box = pm.Binomial("top_box", n=1, p=ps, shape=(n_obs), observed=observations)

        trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=2000, target_accept=0.95)
    return trace

observations, taster_of_obs, formula_of_obs = generate_observations()
trace = run_model(observations, taster_of_obs, formula_of_obs)
pm.plot_trace(trace)
```